# How does parallax scrolling work?

Tags: javascript, html

Was looking around some of [these](http://www.lexusls.asia/), and [these](http://flashvhtml.com/), and [these](http://www.tedxguc.com/) and more [like this](http://hotdot.pro/en/) and [finally this](http://nasaprospect.com/) websites; and wondering how they work?

What front-end/back-end technologies make it possible?

How can I incorporate parallax scrolling in my project?

Comment: As the actual front-end developer of HotDot, which you've mentioned here, I can say that the answer to a question is a vast article on its own and not suited for SO too much.
Yet, in a nutshell, you need to calculate positions of divs-layers wihtin you JavaScript. And those layers should be absolute positioned and use hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually done via javascript and/or css.  Do a View Source in Chrome on the sites you linked and you should be able to see the approaches they took to make it work.